# Остановка музыки запущенной при OnCreate

Tags: android, activity, аудио

```
public class Form1 extends ActionBarActivity {
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    Context context;
...
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_form1);

    if (mp==null) {
        context = this;
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.drawable.mainmenus);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    };
....
    public void startbook(View view) {

          mp.pause();
          mp.stop();
          mp.reset();
          mp.release();
          mp = null;

        Intent intent = new Intent(Form1.this, Form2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

При нажатии на кнопку startbook, звук не останавливается. Причем если запуск звука повесить на что-то вроде:

```
public void startmuz(View view) {
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.drawable.mainmenus);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();
}
```

Звук и стартует и останавливается нормально. Но! Нужно чтоб звук начинал воспроизводится при открытии activity автоматически. Что при вышеуказанном коде не получается ну никак.

Answer (score 1):

Внимательно проверьте, чтобы `mp` не был локальным в `onCreate()` и больше нигде не переопределялся. В `startbook()` он должен быть тем же, что и инициализировался в `onCreate()`. Лучше проверьте дебагером, или выведите значение в консоль через Log.v.

Кроме того, лучше запускайте плеер в `onStart()` и обязательно останавливайте в `onStop()` (если он ещё не был остановлен), иначе есть риск его потерять запущенным. Возможно, лучше будет вынести MediaPlayer в сервис.

И никогда так не делайте:

```
context = this;
```

Comment: Помогло mp обьявить как: . public static MediaPlayer mp= null;

Answer (score 0):

Помогло mp обьявить как: . public static MediaPlayer mp= null;